# Pass ArrayList to an array , raised (Invalid procedure call or argument)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist

Basically I need to benefit from `ArrayList` to sort an array.
the included code works correctly until line `arr = arrlist` , it raises:

> Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

```
Sub Arrlist_to_Array()

    Dim arrlist As Object
    Dim arr() As Variant, item As Variant
    
    Set arrlist = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    arr = Array("5", "7", "4")
    
    For Each item In arr
         arrlist.Add item
       Next
       
    arrlist.Sort
    
    arr = arrlist
    
End Sub
```

great thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sort an Array Using an Array List

- You can't assign an array list (object) to an array. The array list is not a range object. That would be the same as trying to use e.g. `arr = Worksheets(1)`.
- Use its `ToArray` method instead:

  ```
  arr = arrlist.ToArray
  ```
- Note that if you have Microsoft 365, you can use

  ```
  arr = Application.Sort(arr, , , 1)
  ```

  and be finally done with any `ArrayList` business.
- Note that the `ToArray` method always returns a zero-based array while Excel's `Sort` function returns a one-based array, no matter the value of `Option Base`.

Comment: I have office 2016 ,  `arr = arrlist.ToArray` works perfectly